# qemu-kvm missing

Tags: kvm, qemu

I installed qemu-kvm as follows (in rhel7.2):

```
yum install –y qemu-kvm virt-install bridge-utils libvirt libvirt-python libguestfs-tools
```

When I try to run the 'qemu-kvm' command as follows:

```
qemu-kvm –name VM1 -cdrom RedHat-7.2-x86_64.iso –m 512 -cpu 2 –drive file=/root/vm/redhat7.qcow2 -boot d
```

I get this error message:

> bash: /usr/bin/qemu-kvm: No such file or directory

And why I try to use 'virt-install' as follows:

```
virt-install --name VM1 --memory 10240 --vcpus=2 --os-type=Linux --os-variant=rhel7.2 --location=rhel-server-7.6-x86_64-dvd.iso  --network network=default  --network bridge=nm-bridge --console pty,target_type=serial --graphics=vnc -v
```

I get this error message:

> ERROR    Host does not support virtualization type 'hvm'

I also get this message when it's jyst virt-install:

```
virt-install
```

> ERROR    Host does not support any virtualization options

Content of /usr/bin :

```
ls /usr/bin | grep -i qemu
```

> qemu-ga
> qemu-img
> qemu-io
> qemu-nbd

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i vmx
```

> flags     : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq **vmx** ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch arat tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xsaves
> flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq **vmx** ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch arat tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xsaves

Any ideas on what the problem might be or on how I can fix it ?

Comment: It doesn’t appear that your CPU supports virtualization.  What are the flags in /process/cpuinfo?  Are you running RHEL on a physical machine or is it a VM itself?

Comment: @jsbillings I'm running it on VMWare but I've enabled the virtualization for my CPU. When I run "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i vmx" I get an output.

Comment: What does `lsmod | grep kvm` return?

Comment: kvm_intel             162153  0 \
kvm                   525259  1 kvm_intel

Comment: Your user probably doesn’t have access to /dev/kvm.  Try as a user that does, or as root,

Comment: Yes, I've been using root the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by running:

```
ln -s /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm /usr/bin/qemu-kvm
```

It thought it didn't work at first because it showed me this error:

> qemu-kvm: relocation error: /lib64/libspice-server.so.1: symbol SSL_CONF_CTX_set_ssl_ctx, version libssl.so.10 not defined in file libssl.so.10 with link time reference

Turned out I needed to update openssl, I ran:

```
yum update openssl
```

And it worked.